# How to test multiple variables for empty string

Tags: bash, sh

I want to test multiple variables to see if they are empty. So I did the following:

```
if [ test -z "$VAR1" ] || [ test -z "$VAR2" ]
then
   echo "Empty!"
fi
```

However, it doesn't work. The output is:

```
[: -z: binary operator expected
[: -z: binary operator expected
```

What have I done wrong? The code above works fine if I leave out the **OR** (||) condition.

Comment: `if [[ -z "$VAR1" || -z "$VAR2" ]]; then ... fi` should work in `bash`

Comment: `[` *is* `test`, not part of the `if` statement's syntax. Type `help [` and `help test` at the prompt for more information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use either brackets or the `test` command, don't use both. Either of the following will work:

```
if [ -z "$VAR1" ] || [ -z "$VAR2" ]
then
   echo "Empty!"
fi
```

Or:

```
if test -z "$VAR1" || test -z "$VAR2"
then
   echo "Empty!"
fi
```

In some older shells `[` was just an alias for the `test` command. You could even miss out the closing `]` (or add it after `test`) and everything would be fine. Nowadays, on `bash` this will give a syntax error. However, the two (correct) syntaxes are still functionally equivalent and can be used interchangeably but not at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

You should either use `test`, or `[`; they are synonymous, except `[` requires a `]` as last argument.

```
[ -z "$VAR1" ] || [ -z "$VAR2" ]
```

or

```
test -z "$VAR1" || test -z "$VAR2"
```